# Handling Content Disposition using AJAX POST request

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, jsp, content-disposition

I am trying to send a value selected from the dropdown list to the backend in a jsp page. Once the value is selected I am using AJAX to show a loading page on the GUI and at the same time making a post request.

```
function requestDocumentsFromGUI(elmnt) {
        var docData = $(elmnt).text();
        document.getElementById('mask1').style.display='block';
        alert("POST Ajax request initiating.... docData : " + docData);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}"+"/generatePDF.htm", 
            data : { 
                    docValue : docData 
            },
        });
    }
```

I am getting response as a PDF file which I have to render on the GUI using "Content Disposition" but I am not sure how to do it. Once the PDF is rendered I have to stop the Loading message on the browser hence I HAVE to use AJAX POST Request. Can someone please help ?

Comment: I would make it so that it gives you a link to click that'd open the relevant pdf in a new page, assuming this is a webapp meant to be un in a browser, not a desktop webapp.